# If A entails C, and B entails C, why doesn’t (A and B) necessarily entail C?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

The original question is in Greek letters Γ and Δ, each representing a set of sentences, and *φ* representing an individual sentence (atomic proposition). The question is from Introduction to Logic by Stanford University available on Coursera. [image]

Comment: @Arno Notice that when *φ* is a compound proposition of the form equivalent to *P → Q*, it is preserved across intersections. Surprisingly, this very instructive detail is explicitly stated only in Chang and Keisler's quite "unfriendly" *Model Theory* (3rd edition, p. 15. Amsterdam: North-Holland, 1990).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `∩` (denoting intersection), not a `∧` (denoting AND) here.

Thus, in the third statement, it could be that sentences present in both `Γ` and `Δ` do not necessarily entail the formula `φ`. `Γ` and `Δ` could have an empty intersection.

For example, given two distinct formulas `ψ1` and `ψ2`,let `Γ` be `{(φ AND ψ1 )}` and let `Δ` be `{(φ AND ψ2)}`.

`Γ |= φ`   and  `Δ |= φ`, but `Γ ∩ Δ` is the empty set, so `Γ ∩ Δ |\= φ`

Comment: There is one additional step needed here, which is that `φ` needs to be given a bit more precisely.  For example, if `φ` were a logical truth then the empty set would in fact entail it.

Comment: This is great help! I think the confusion between intersection and And is exactly the reason why I didn’t understand it. Now it is crystal clear! Thank you!